# Cloth simulation in blender asset browser

Tags: cloth-simulation, asset, library

I want to add my cloth simulation in blender asset library but I am unable to move the cloth only it's origin is changing position. I have also tried parenting it with empty but only it's origin is moving not cloth after moving empty.

Answer (score 0):

By default, a cloth sim, once baked can't be moved. However, if you convert the cloth object into a regular mesh by applying the cloth modifier (or going to object>Convert>Mesh), you can move it just like any other object. Likewise you can add this to your asset library.

This however freezes the simulation at whatever frame you've converted it, since you've essentially turned it into a static object.

If you wanted to keep the object with the ability to re-simulate it at a later date, you should be able to delete the cache and add the object to your asset library. You could then bring this object in to a new project and have the ability to simulate the cloth in that new project.